# Unix command to create a tar of a specified number of files

Tags: unix, command, tar

I am looking for a Unix command which will create a tar of 10 files from a directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
tar cf path_of_tar.tar $(ls | head -10)
```

Add options to ls to select the 10 you want.

Answer (score 3):

The command you're looking for is: [`tar`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar)

How it's usually used:

```
$ tar cf file.tar file1 file2...
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, depending on your needs...

```
$ tar cf tenfiles.tar file1 file2 file3 ... file10
```

That'll do it. You can check out the tar manpage (`$ man tar`) for further details on other options you might need. (Your question was a bit vague, so I can't be that much more specific.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying:

```
man tar
```

This will show all the options available and usage information. A typical usage for creating a tar of files in a directory would look like this:

```
tar -cvf myfiles.tar ./mydirectory
```

where myfiles.tar is the name of the tar file you want to create, and mydirectory is the directory the files reside in.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define what files are they? Are they of a specific filename pattern? My reasoning is asking that you specified 10 files.

In general:

```
tar cvf tar_with_10_files.tar somefile_with_wildcards_or_pattern_matching
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -cvf name.tar /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3 ...
```